# How to define an event handler of MouseLeftButtonDown of program generated Ellipse element of Canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, mouse, mouseleftbuttondown

How to define an event handler of `MouseLeftButtonDown` of program generated Ellipse element of Canvas in WPF? I have something like this:

```
canvas.Children.Add(new Ellipse(){
    Name = "FirstEllipse",
    Width = 150,
    Height = 100,
    Margin = new Thickness(200, 150, 0, 0),
    Fill = Brushes.Red,
    MouseLeftButtonDown = "Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown"
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MouseLeftButtonDown` is not a property but an event. You register a callback to the event using the `+=` operator:

```
var e = new Ellipse { 
              Name = "FirstEllipse", 
              Width = 150, 
              Height = 100, 
              Margin = new Thickness(200, 150, 0, 0), 
              Fill = Brushes.Red };
e.MouseLeftButtonDown += Ellipse_MouseLeftButtonDown;
canvas.Children.Add(e);
```

Comment: And how can I refer specifically to this figure I clicked to change it`s, for example, color?

Comment: The handler has a sender parameter. That is the ellipse.

Comment: Can you give me an example of code. `sender.SetValue(Ellipse.FillProperty, Brushes.Aquamarine);` does not work

Comment: How about `((Ellipse)sender).Fill = Brushes.Aquamarine`?

Comment: Thanks, it helps much. I already figured it out, but your method is more beautiful.